# Spring boot security block non RestController endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an app that is exposing a bunch of endpoints that I did not expect. For example localhost:8080/app/ returns a list of URL that among other things exposes information related to the hibernate entities.

I DO NOT want basic auth enabled as I have my own authentication configured.
But if the URL is not one that is represented by a RestController I have written then I want it to an existing forbidden page that I have.

Here is my current config but it does not prevent the unwanted endpoints:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/**").antMatchers("/v2/**").antMatchers("/webjars/**").antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")
       .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.httpBasic().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    http.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider()).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/v2/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/health").permitAll();
    http.rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeService).useSecureCookie(useSecureCookie);

    //Show 403 on denied access
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Forbidden());
}
```

So in this case localhost:8080/app/api/SearchControler/{var} should work but localhost:8080/app/ should go to my Forbidden entry point. Instead localhost:8080/app/ is going to the spring username and password page.

First off I don't know why these endpoints are even showing up when there is no RestController for them and second why is redirecting to a 403 page so difficult.

I'm not sure what config I am missing.

*** EDIT ***

I have also tried:

```
http.formLogin().and().httpBasic().disabled();
```

as well as:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

and nothing seems to stop spring from taking over and doing whatever it feels like doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try again after removing `super.configure(http);` in your `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method.

Documentation

> Override this method to configure the {@link HttpSecurity}. Typically
>   subclasses     * should not invoke this method by calling super as it
>   may override their     * configuration. The default configuration is:
>   `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();`

Comment: I have tried with and without the super call and neither work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is more configuration which you didn't show to as, but anyway:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    //this is only for ignoring static resources in your app, sth that is never changed (you can cash it) and public (available for any user on the internet (ex. /js /css - sth else static img etc)
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**").antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //super.configure(http); this call the default configuration, if you implement this method you shouldn't call the default one
    http.httpBasic().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    http.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider())
        .authorizeRequests() // the order is matter here, if antMatchers() will match the request the others after him will not be checked, anyRequest() will match any request, so it should be at the end 
      //.permitAll().antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**").permitAll() - there is no need to duplicate what is in web.ignoring() - such requests will not reach this point 

        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    http.rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeService).useSecureCookie(useSecureCookie);

    //Show 403 on denied access
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Forbidden());
}
```

Comment: This config routes every request to the spring basic auth login page.  how is it that http.httpBasic().disable(); does not kill everything in the spring basic auth?  it seems to me that it should.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is completely related to transitive dependencies.  After removing some dependencies and adding excludes to others the core problem has been solved.